# Android png button design issue

Tags: android, xml, button

I've put a grey background into my layout so it's very different from white, but now there is white space within the buttons occupied space which makes everything really ugly and I'm wondering how you fix that to match your background color?

Screenshot:

[image: How it looks]

The Button XML:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/arrow"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="27dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bluebtn"
    android:rotation="90"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: You probably want to add transparency instead of white for your graphics background

Answer (score 0):

If you want to occupy the `Button` parent width and height you should use `0dp`:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/arrow"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bluebtn"
    android:rotation="90"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout#developer-guide):

> Using 0dp, which is the equivalent of "MATCH_CONSTRAINT"

Comment: @Karlay have this helped you?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ImageButton and set the button 
attribute to null

```
<ImageButton
     ...
     android:button="@null"
     android:background=“@drawable/bluebtn”
     ...
 />
```

If that doesn’t work then it means your image does not have a transparent background and you need to make a new bluebtn drawable with a transparent background.